# Configuring asynchronous loggers in log4j2.properties not working

Tags: log4j2

The configuration for making adminLogger asynchronous using
log4j2.properties is not working. I have used the below lines to make
the logger asynchronous.

```
appender.adminAppender.type = RollingFile
appender.adminAppender.name = AdminAppender
appender.adminAppender.fileName = ${adminLogFile}
appender.adminAppender.filePattern = ${logPath}/admin-Backup-%i.log
appender.adminAppender.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.adminAppender.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss.SSS} %-5p %c{1} [%t]: %m%n
appender.adminAppender.policies.type = Policies
appender.adminAppender.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.adminAppender.policies.size.size = 10MB
appender.adminAppender.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.adminAppender.strategy.max = 5

logger.adminLogger.type = asyncLogger
logger.adminLogger.name = admin
logger.adminLogger.level = debug
logger.adminLogger.additivity = false
logger.adminLogger.appenderRefs = adminAppender
logger.adminLogger.appenderRef.adminAppender.ref = AdminAppender
```

What is the correct way to configure it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "is not working"? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If I remove the line logger.adminLogger.type = asyncLogger, then its initializing the synchronous logger and writing to the file.  If I use this line, its not initializing the logger at all. I have used the Configurator.initialize(null, filePath) to load the properties file

Comment: Why don't you enable the debug logs of log4j logger and check?